# how do i select 3 different datetimes frome database with one statement?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

so I'm currently working on some Statistics. for that, I need 3 datetimes one between 7:50 and 8:10, one between 11:50 and 12:10, and one between 14:50 and 15:10.

```
SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE zone = 5 and updated >='2020-08-12 07:50:00' AND updated <'2020-08-12 15:10:00'
```

so this ^^ would give me all data from 7:50 to 15:10 and the problem with that is that I have to pull from my school's database which isnt very efficient because that one statement would give me about 580 rows of data and my stuff doesn't work with that much data, therefore, I'm trying to limit the amount of data I pull

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - although I cannot imagine a scenario whereby 580 rows is data could be considered anything other than trivial.

Comment: Why not doing so with 3 different statements (and each returns no more than 1 result)? It should be a piece of cake with a LIMIT clause in a [select statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT humidity, zone, temperature, updated FROM sensor WHERE zone = 8 and ((updated > '2020-08-12 08:00:00' and updated < '2020-08-12 08:05:00') or (updated > '2020-08-12 12:00:00' and updated < '2020-08-12 12:05:00') or (updated > '2020-08-12 15:00:00' AND updated < '2020-08-12 15:05:00'))"
```

this selects all the times in one statement :)

Answer (score 0):

As @koala-yeung mentioned, sounds like 3 queries will do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE zone = 5 and updated >='2020-08-12 07:50:00' AND updated <'2020-08-12 08:10:00' LIMIT 1;
```

and repeat for the other two timeslots.

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to have one statement instead of calling the database 3 times?

Comment: @kristroffer-clausen Sure, I just went for simplicity / readability :)  The combination of AND/OR you found should be fine.